# How does "personalization" work in OverflowAI?

Tags: support, overflow-ai

Reading [this registration](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/search/?utm_source=house-ads&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=alpha-recruitment&utm_content=sign-up-now) link to OverflowAI, I notice the following in the "Feature set" section:

> Personalization: Ability to configure preferences (answer length,
> technical level)

If someone comes with a question, I guess this person does not know the answer. Not knowing the answer means, and correct me if I am wrong, that the asker is not (fully?) aware of the technical level required, and somehow related, answer length, required to answer the question.

#### Questions

- If the settings say "low technical level", but the question requires a high technical level, the answer will not be presented to the asker?
- Why providing such a feature to users while they may not know what configuration they need to find the answer?
- What happens if I am lazy and want and one line answer, while every single answer to my problem are "book sized"?

Comment: I suspect these are custom prompt settings, which is already a feature in existing LLMs. For example, instead of it being prompted to "summarize the answers above" it could be "summarize the answers above for someone who's just learning to code". I suspect the answer to most of your other questions will be found during beta testing.